# How to prevent launching of second copy of application?

Tags: android

I need to guarantee that my Android application won't be launched twice. How to do it? I mean in ideal I would need in case of second launch just switch to primary copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `android:launchMode` More on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife), it shouldn't be possible to start a second copy on an activity. If it isn't terminated, it will resume the running instance.

Comment: You can most definitely have multiple "copies" of activities running. The lifecycle chart has nothing to do with this

Comment: Andrew: I know that I have managed to launch several copies of my application... How you can explain it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal behavior of app launching.  You don't need to do anything special.  (And definitely do not at all use the android:launchMode="singleInstance" option.  That is a very special behavior that is probably not what you want.)